# "Error: Too many re-renders" when using navigationEvents in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

The following code renders a Modal when modalVisible is true. My plan is to set modal visible to true everytime, the screen gets shown. I want to do this using navigationEvents onDidBlur.

my code is this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Modal, StyleSheet, Text, Pressable, View } from "react-native";
import GestureRecognizer from 'react-native-swipe-gestures';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation'

const CreationScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true);

return (
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
      <NavigationEvents
    onDidBlur={setModalVisible(true)}
    />
      <GestureRecognizer onSwipeDown={ () => setModalVisible(false) }>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
      >
        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <Pressable style={styles.aboveModalView} onPress={() => {setModalVisible(false)}} />
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
              onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('camera'), setModalVisible(false)}}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Camera</Text>
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
              onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('cameraRoll'), setModalVisible(false)}}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Upload from Gallery</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      </GestureRecognizer>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Now every time I go on the screen, I get the error message:

Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

I also tried out different navigation events as e.g. onWillBlur etc. but it gave the same error.

Does anyone know why this happens? Btw I am using react-navigation v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by just using withNavigation:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Modal, StyleSheet, Text, Pressable, View } from "react-native";
import GestureRecognizer from 'react-native-swipe-gestures';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation'

const CreationScreen = ({navigation, props}) => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true);

   navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
      setModalVisible(true)
    });

  return (
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
      <GestureRecognizer onSwipeDown={ () => setModalVisible(false) }>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
      >
        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <Pressable style={styles.aboveModalView} onPress={() => {setModalVisible(false), navigation.navigate('feed')}} />
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
              onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('camera'), setModalVisible(false)}}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Camera</Text>
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
              onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('cameraRoll'), setModalVisible(false)}}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Upload from Gallery</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      </GestureRecognizer>
    </View>
  );
};
```